# GPUImage: to use or not to use smoothlyScaleOutput

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage

I am using `GPUImage` for applying filters in my app (using it to apply one value filters to still photos). I'm trying to decide if I need to use `smoothlyScaleOutput` or not. The downside of it is it takes a long time to load large photos. I've read Brad Larson say:

> The smoothlyScaleOutput: option for a photo tells the framework to use
>   trilinear filtering when downsampling the photo. That is, for large
>   photos that you're shrinking down, it will produce a much smoother
>   output. If you don't need to shrink a photo, you can turn that off for
>   better performance and a slightly sharper picture.

Just curious but for those out there who've used `GPUImage` in the same fashion that I am, is it worth it for me to enable this option? It's hard for me to tell the difference, but I've only sampled a handful of photos using some of the basic filters (brightness, contrast, sepia, etc.).

Also was confused about what might constitute shrinking a photo. Would that mean using UIImage drawInRect to draw the photo at a smaller resolution? Or would that mean taking a large photo and transforming its size to fit in a UIImageView? Or both?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.